# How to serialize iterator to CSV with Jackson

Tags: csv, serialization, iterator, jackson

(Jackson 2.8.7)

I am trying to serialize an Iterator of objects with the following code:

```
static final CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
static final CsvSchema networkSchema = csvMapper.schemaFor(NetworkRecord.class).withHeader();

static final CsvFactory factory = newFactory();

private static CsvFactory newFactory(){
    CsvFactory factory = new CsvFactory();
    factory.setCodec(csvMapper);
    return factory;
}

static void serializeNetworks(final Iterator<NetworkRecord> records, final OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    try(final CsvGenerator generator = factory.createGenerator(os)){
        generator.setSchema(networkSchema);
        generator.writeObject(records);
        generator.flush();
    }
}
```

However, the output only contains the header and none of the value rows. (If I serialize the objects from a while loop, everything works as expected.) How can I make Jackson serialize the Iterator correctly?

Comment: what is factory and networkSchema? Also do you use https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv  dependency?

Comment: added the code for the factory and other static variables. Maven dependency is  groupId: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat, artifactId: jackson-dataformat-csv. I am still on version 2.8 while Jackson master is currently 2.9